# How can I write the all laravel exception message into particular file. Such as Model exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My question is that how to I am write the all laravel exception message into particular file - such as Model exception.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for here. Is it about translation of the actual message?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for all Exceptions in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` and do your checks and writes to a file or any other logic. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors#the-exception-handler)

For Example:

```php
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
...

public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        //write to file
    }

    parent::report($exception);
}
```